# Where is the state and setState lit-element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

Coming from a react background, i was wondering where is the state and setState equivalent in lit-element, i couldn't find anything useful in lit-element docs. is it private property? or `requestUpdate`?

Comment: Do you mean the `properties`? I think those act as the "state"; every time you set a property, the element is updated/rerendered. https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle#haschanged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `state` in LitElement, at least not directly.

What you have is a set of `properties` that you define in the `static get properties()` getter.

They act more or less like `state` does in rect, everytime one of those `properties` change, the element is updated.

Comment: Are there any best practices available for lit-element if you would like to create immutable properties?

Comment: And `properties` are visible from the outside, and modifiable. So they're not private. It seems they are closer to React `props`. Is there a concept of "private state" in LitElement?

Comment: You do have a `@internalProperty()` decorator that you can use for internal properties that should only be changed from within the component https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/modules/_lit_element_.html#internalproperty